# Unable to get the output from d3.js code?

Tags: d3.js

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
<script>
    var dset=[40,50,60];
    var dvar=d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", 500)
.attr("height", 500);


 var ba=dset.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dset)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width",function(d){return d;})
    .attr("hetight",50);
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Context : In this line of code selectAll() function is not working

Comment: Instead of `dset.selectAll("rect")` it should have been `dvar.selectAll("rect")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Have made small mistakes. Run below code and it will work.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
<script>
var dset=[40,50,60];
var dvar=d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", 500)
.attr("height", 500);


var ba= dvar
.selectAll("rect")
.data(dset)
.enter()
.append("rect")
.attr("width",function(d){return d;})
.attr("height",50);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In your example you can only see single box. If you want to see all the boxes, you need to add below code after attr("height", 50).

```
.attr("y", function(d, i){
    return i * 100;
});
```

Full code is as under :-

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
<script>
var dset=[40,50,60];
var dvar=d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", 500)
.attr("height", 500);


var ba= dvar
.selectAll("rect")
.data(dset)
.enter()
.append("rect")
.attr("width",function(d){return d;})
.attr("height",50)
.attr("y", function(d, i){
                            return i * 100;
                        });;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was Just tying to see the single box.But the same code which i mentioned was executed in other systems. When i ran this on my browser i was unable get the output.

Comment: I dont know how its working cause you are defining something else and using something else.

I mean you are defining "dVar" and using dset (var ba= "dset".selectAll("rect"))

You can use my code it should work on all browser